# errors installing python on termux android N OS

Tags: android, python, terminal, apt-get, apt

I just recently got a pixel c and immediately upgraded to the beta for android (7.0), however I have been unable to install some packages in termux, such as python.

`uname -a` yields `Linux localhost 3.18.0-09959-gef15d9c #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Feb 26 10:37:48 PST 2016 armv8l Android`

then when I try to install a package that I know exists, because I have checked on it using apt list I get:

```
apt install python2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python2
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Have you run `apt update && apt upgrade` recently to ensure you have the latest version of the system?

Comment: Worked for me do u know why this is necessary?

Comment: @partizanos It could be that the downloaded list of available packages (the package index) needed to be updated in order to have the python2 package data.

Answer (score -1):

Change the installer:

pip install python2

or

pip3 install phyton2